# Quicksort implementation in Python

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I'm trying to implement quicksort in python. However, my code doesn't properly sort (not quite). For example, on the input array [5,3,4,2,7,6,1], my code outputs [1,2,3,5,4,6,7]. So, the end result interposes the 4 and 5. I admit I am a bit rusty on python as I've been studying ML (and was fairly new to python before that). I'm aware of other python implementations of quicksort, and other similar questions on Stack Overflow about python and quicksort, but I am trying to understand what is wrong with this chunk of code that I wrote myself:

```
#still broken 'quicksort'

def partition(array):
    pivot = array[0]
    i = 1 
    for j in range(i, len(array)):
        if array[j] < array[i]:
            temp = array[i]
            array[i] = array[j]
            array[j] = temp
            i += 1
    array[0] = array[i]
    array[i] = pivot
    return array[0:(i)], pivot, array[(i+1):(len(array))]

def quick_sort(array):
    if len(array) <= 1: #if i change this to if len(array) == 1 i get an index out of bound error
        return array 

    low, pivot, high = partition(array)
    #quick_sort(low)
    #quick_sort(high)

    return quick_sort(low) + [pivot] + quick_sort(high)

array = [5,3,4,2,7,6,1]

print quick_sort(array)
# prints [1,2,3,5,4,6,7]
```

Comment: Not really the problem but you can do swaps in python like this: `a, b = b, a`

Answer (score 6):

I'm a little confused about what the algorithm's connection to quicksort is. In quicksort, you typically compare all entries against a pivot, so you get a lower and higher group; the quick_sort function clearly expects your partition function to do this.

However, in the partition function, you never compare anything against the value you name pivot. All comparisons are between index i and j, where j is incremented by the for loop and i is incremented if an item was found out of order. Those comparisons include checking an item against itself. That algorithm is more like a selection sort with a complexity slightly worse than a bubble sort. So you get items bubbling left as long as there are enough items to the left of them, with the first item finally dumped after where the last moved item went; since it was never compared against anything, we know this must be out of order if there are items left of it, simply because it replaced an item that was in order.

Thinking a little more about it, the items are only partially ordered, since you do not return to an item once it has been swapped to the left, and it was only checked against the item it replaced (now found to have been out of order). I think it is easier to write the intended function without index wrangling:

```
def partition(inlist):
    i=iter(inlist)
    pivot=i.next()
    low,high=[],[]
    for item in i:
        if item<pivot:
            low.append(item)
        else:
            high.append(item)
    return low,pivot,high
```

Answer (score 3):

You might find these reference implementations helpful while trying to understand your own.

---

**Returning a new list:**

```
def qsort(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    head, *tail = array
    less = qsort([i for i in tail if i < head])
    more = qsort([i for i in tail if i >= head])
    return less + [head] + more
```

---

**Sorting a list in place:**

```
def quicksort(array):
    _quicksort(array, 0, len(array) - 1)

def _quicksort(array, start, stop):
    if stop - start > 0:
        pivot, left, right = array[start], start, stop
        while left <= right:
            while array[left] < pivot:
                left += 1
            while array[right] > pivot:
                right -= 1
            if left <= right:
                array[left], array[right] = array[right], array[left]
                left += 1
                right -= 1
        _quicksort(array, start, right)
        _quicksort(array, left, stop)
```

---

**Generating sorted items from an iterable:**

```
def qsort(sequence):
    iterator = iter(sequence)
    try:
        head = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    else:
        try:
            tail, more = chain(next(iterator), iterator), []
            yield from qsort(split(head, tail, more))
            yield head
            yield from qsort(more)
        except StopIteration:
            yield head

def chain(head, iterator):
    yield head
    yield from iterator

def split(head, tail, more):
    for item in tail:
        if item < head:
            yield item
        else:
            more.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `pivot` ends up needing to stay in the initial position (b/c it is the lowest value), you swap it with some other element anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Read the Fine Manual :

Quick sort explanation and python implementation :

http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheQuickSort.html

Comment: [20, 26, 17, 31, 44, 54, 77, 55, 93] is what my code now outputs for the test at the bottom of your link, Jerome Radix, so clearly I've still got issues. . .

Comment: alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]  
print quick_sort(alist)  
print(alist)

Comment: Saying "print quick_sort(alist)" my code puts out the correct answer but if I say quick_sort(alist) and then print(alist) it puts out that weird order, so it's like for whatever reason my code is partially sorting the array itself in place (but for the most part no). But my code *does* in fact sort the array correctly now that I corrected it, but you have to call it the "right" way (which is annoying) cause it doesn't sort the list in place.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this should be a comment, but it has too complicated structure for a comment.

See what happens for array being `[7, 8]`:

- pivot = 7
- i = 1
- `for` loop does nothing
- `array[0]` becomes `array[i]` which is 8
- `array[i]` becomes `pivot` which is 7
- you return `array[0:1]` and `pivot`, which are `[8, 7]` and `7` (the third subexpression ignored)...

If you explicitly include the returned `pivot` in concatenation, you should skip it in the array returned.

Answer (score 1):

okay i "fixed" it, at least on the *one* input i've tried it on (and idk why... python issues)

```
def partition(array):   
    pivot = array[0]   
    i = 1   
    for j in range(i, len(array)):   
        if array[j] < pivot:   
            temp = array[i]   
            array[i] = array[j]   
            array[j] = temp   
            i += 1   
    array[0] = array[i-1]  
    array[i-1] = pivot  
    return array[0:i-1], pivot, array[i:(len(array))]  


def quick_sort(array):  
    if len(array) <= 1:  
        return array   

    low, pivot, high = partition(array)  
    #quick_sort (low)  
    #quick_sort (high)  

    return quick_sort (low) + [pivot] + quick_sort (high)  



array = [5,3,4,2,7,6,1]  

print quick_sort(array)  
# prints [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Comment: Yep, this code works.. but it still obscures how in a rather hard effort to make it operate in place, which seems weird as it just destroys the order of the input list with one pass, without sorting it all the way. Things like slicing to len(array) is just distractingly verbose.